# Setting schedule timer in Firebase Analytics for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I've got Firebase Analytics set up in my application and has the following messages in debug log:

```
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): 2122.100666046143
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Upload task scheduled to be executed in approx. (s): 2122.100666046143
```

So the analytics actually sends data to the server when this timer ends or the user quits the application.

Is there a way to set up this timer value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that Firebase Analytics will send data to the server when the timer ends (usually in every hour) or the app goes to background. To conserve battery, Firebase Analytics tries not to send data too often. There is currently no way to set up the timer to send data.

Comment: Sad, but true.. Thanx, Alex.